# UITabbarController + ABPeoplePickerNavigationController not working properly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitabbar

Currently I am using ABPeoplePickerNavigationController along with UITabbarController and want to open ABPeoplePickerNavigationController in UITabbarController's index 2..

So on viewcontroller at index 2, I had written code like this,

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *newControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [self.tabBarController viewControllers]];
    [picker.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];
    [newControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:2 withObject: picker];
    [self.tabBarController setViewControllers: newControllers animated: NO];
    [picker release];
}
```

but when I had written this code, suddenly the title of tabbar changed from contacts to Groups and image not showing..

How can we show the title and image for this tabbar as before....

Please help me to solve this problem..

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please write this code in your

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

method after

`[self.window addSubview:tabBarController.view];`

```
UITabBarItem *tabItem = [[[self.tabBarController tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:TAB_INDEX];
[tabItem setTitle:@"Contacts"];
tabItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"YOUR IMAGE"];
```

Happy Coding....